# Meaning of feats in syntaxnet

Tags: nlp, syntaxnet

I am using syntaxnet in Spanish and I have found that all the words have a field called "feats" whose format depends on the type of word (noun, pronoun, verb). There are some fields whose meaning is obvious, but in other cases I cannot figure out what it is showing. For example, this is the case of fields such as "fPOS" or "Case" in pronouns. Is there any guide or list with explanations avaiable?

Answer (score 0):

Universal features are documented [here](http://universaldependencies.org/u/overview/morphology.html#features) .